# I'd like to know "How can I click (enter) the link with the png image containing link??"

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Can anyone please help me
I am very new in python. I'd like to know "How can I click (enter) the link with the png image containing link??" In this case dashboard.

html code:

CSS Selector: #resultTable > tbody:nth-child(2) > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(8) > a:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1)

Xpath: /html/body/div/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/a/img

Please help.

Have a nice day.
Please see the attached SS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rldHO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the **/img** from your XPath/CSS selector.
You should locate and click on the **<a>** element.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[8]/a').click()
```

Side note:
It's better to keep the locators as short as possible.
For instance, for XPath you can read about relative XPath expressions [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-the-difference-between-relative-and-absolute-xpath-in-selenium)

Comment: @SubrotoPaul, glad to hear that!
You can mark it as an answer, to not display your question as one w/o an answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77821731/insecurerequestwarning-markupresembleslocatorwarning

Can you please help me with this issue???